# PostgreSQL before insert trigger for blocking 0000-00-00 00:00:00

Tags: postgresql, triggers, insert, timestamp

I have created the following trigger in my PostgreSQL environment to block the inserts of **0000-00-00 00:00:00** in my **timestamp** datatype field, since it's not supported.

```
create function my_trigger_func() returns trigger as $$
begin
    if NEW.t_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' then
        NEW.t_date := '0001-01-01 00:00:00';
    end if;
    return new;
end
$$ language plpgsql;

CREATE TRIGGER my_trigger
BEFORE INSERT ON timezone.test
FOR EACH ROW
EXECUTE PROCEDURE my_trigger_func()
```

The above trigger function gets created successfully. But after that, when I execute the below insert command:

```
Insert into timezone.test (t_id,t_date) values ('3','0001-01-01 01:10:01');
```

I am getting the following error:

```
ERROR:  date/time field value out of range: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
LINE 1: SELECT NEW.t_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
                            ^
QUERY:  SELECT NEW.t_date = '0000-00-00 00:00:00'
CONTEXT:  PL/pgSQL function my_trigger_func() line 3 at IF
********** Error **********

ERROR: date/time field value out of range: "0000-00-00 00:00:00"
SQL state: 22008
Context: PL/pgSQL function my_trigger_func() line 3 at IF
```

Kindly let me know where am I going wrong.

Answer (score 2):

> Kindly let me know where am I going wrong.

Simple, you try to compare:

```
IF NEW.t_date          = '0000-00-00 00:00:00' THEN
   (type timestamp)      literal -> conversion to Timestamp
```

`'0000-00-00 00:00:00'` -> Invalid timestamp

And because of this trigger you cannot insert even correct values. I would suggest correcting it in application and insert proper values.

Comment: Which seems to indicate that you did not need the trigger in the first place (the database would reject the invalid data anyway). What you maybe want is a custom function that converts from varchar to date and fixes invalid input in the way you describe (or just let the application code handle it).

Comment: @lad2025: Thanks for your comment. But isn't there way to modify the above trigger to ignore those values and instead replace them with the correct ones.

Comment: @Thilo Can you please let me guide me more as to how can I create this custom function before inserts happen. The reason I am saying this, my table has many columns and because of this un-supported timestamp, nothing is getting populated in other columns which are required. Hence, I wanted to make a trigger at the database level to correct those values, so that the whole insert doesn't fail. I hope you understand